# How to execute apk inside another apk

Tags: android, apk

i'm developing an app that runs in some tablets. these tablets are rooted and the user that uses that can't go out the single app that tablet run. If i want to use an external app inside my app is possible? Like an emulator inside my app.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically to run android application inside android application you need and android emulator on your Android device, which needs lots of CPU, and is neither implemented now, nor a good solution for any problem that you may be facing. Theoretically it's possible but technically - very complicated and to my mind useless.

You should try to find a more elegant solution rather than this. The simplest thing you can do is to make incapsulated switching mechanism between your restricted apps or think about solution how this apps can be integrated.